# Publish App exchange application with Scanning

Tags: lightning-aura-components, salesforce-id, security-review, partner-communities, chimera-security-scanner

I have created a Lightning component And Add in App Exchange my partner community. So I have passed my component in a security review. Now I can use 
SOURCE SCANNER for Apex class and visual force page scan.Check Link :- ***https://security.secure.force.com/sourcescanner/CloudScannerMain***
But I am trying to scan my Org at that time I have to get Comments like ***'Invalid email: Partners may not use a personal email address'***. Any suggestion please, let me now.

Comment: Hi @Divya, welcome to SFSE, instead of asking a new question; please update your original question with this details as mentioned in it by Phil : [Scanning Salesforce Application for security review](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/263876/scanning-salesforce-application-for-security-review)

Answer (score 0):

Did you go through the documentation at https://security.secure.force.com/security/tools/forcecom/scannerhelp#Partners?
Are you using your official email id but still facing an issue?

If your company is small and has a domain without email - explore platforms like Mailgun to sign up for free email to be associated your domain.